# How to perform Graph auth without hosting my bot in Azure?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

From my understanding, the OAuthPrompt requires a connection name. To create this, I need to make use of the Bot Channels Registration (as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Ccsharp%2Cbot-oauth)). However, this seems to require me to create an Azure account and enter my payment card details. I would like to avoid entering my details if possible as I would not like to be charged for using any Azure services. Is there any way to avoid this?

If I must manually handle the OAuth process, I would like my sign-in to pop up in a small window like the "Allow" button triggers within the Who bot. I have tried SignIn cards which I have read just don't work in teams, and I have also tried OpenUrl type actions in a card which, when pressed, open the URL in my browser as opposed to a pop-up. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Bot Framework bot (only for Microsoft Teams) using the guidance here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-create. To summarize that article, you can use this endpoint to create a non-Azure bot: https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new

If you chose to use the Azure Bot Framework, you will not be charged for the Bot Framework if Microsoft Teams is your only channel (this does NOT include your web service if you chose to host your bot code on Azure, although you can chose a free tier to avoid any charges).

For authentication, see this section of the MS Teams documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/authentication. Depending on how you chose to implement your authentication, there are a few articles in that section that may apply. The OAuth card does work in Teams (not the free version, does not work with guest accounts, and only works for Azure bots).

For authentication, if you're redirecting to a different domain make sure you add it to the validDomains in your app manifest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about the Graph channel? Would this be a chargeable channel?

Comment: Further to the OAuthCards, I'm receiving "BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 500 ERROR - Error: Unknown attachment type" when I try sending a card created using CardFactory.oauthCard

Comment: What do you mean by Graph channel?

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT Sorry, maybe channel isn't the correct terminology, I'm referring to the OAuth Connection Settings in the Bot Channels Registration page. I'm unsure of the charges around this functionality and whether if I have a 12 month free account, then this functionality might be lost when it expires.

If charges are possible, I would prefer to avoid this authentication method and instead handle it myself, but for this I would like to use a pop-up window similar to the Who bot, rather than opening in my web browser. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: After further reading, I think I lacked an understanding of what channels were. I guess my question now is can I configure the OAuth Connection Settings for the Teams channel of my app without having to make an Azure account. If I did make an Azure account, would Iose this functionality after me free tier 12 months has ended? I haven't used the Azure portal yet and only have used the dev.botframework.com or app studio website to register my bots.

Comment: OAuthCard only works with bots created in Azure, not bots created through the legacy portal. You'd need to roll your own auth w/o it. See this sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node. My apologies for not calling that out in my original answer (I've updated it to reflect)

Comment: @AndrewClear Thanks for your help. Is there anyway I can perform my own auth with the small pop-up window similar to auth in the Who bot, or will the login page always have to open in my main browser?

Comment: Yes, please see the sample I linked to in a previous comment. There are examples of how to do that in there.

Comment: @AndrewClear thanks for your help! I've managed to get this working. My issue was that the domain in my sign in button wasn't added to my valid URLs 

Comment: Thanks for following up with the final solution, I've edited my answer to include that as well.